# How to load swf file from byteArray?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash, arrays

I'm working with the AIR application which loads the encrypted SWF from hard disc and decrypt this swf. After that I have byteArray of decrypted swf and I want to load it in Loader or SWFLoader.

```
private var file_byte:ByteArray;
private var myFileStream:FileStream;
private static var inputFile:File;
private var loader:Loader;

private function loadSWF(url:String):void
{
    inputFile = new File(url);
    myFileStream = new FileStream();
    myFileStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completed);
    myFileStream.openAsync(inputFile, FileMode.READ);
    file_byte = new ByteArray();
}

private function completed(event:Event):void 
{
    myFileStream.readBytes(file_byte, 0, myFileStream.bytesAvailable);

    //Decrypting file 
    file_byte = decrypt(file_byte);

    // Prepare the loader context to avoid security error
    var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
    loaderContext.allowLoadBytesCodeExecution = true;
    loaderContext.allowCodeImport = true;

    // Load the SWF file    
    loader = new Loader();  
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onChildComplete); 
    loader.loadBytes(file_byte,loaderContext);
}

private function onChildComplete(e : Event) : void
{
    this.addChild(loader);
}
```

Security Error:

```
Error #3207: Application-sandbox content cannot access this feature.
at flash.system::Security$/allowDomain()
at rfx::MainTimeline_cbc00d6d7b3a063d505c336e0c8f32a1()[constructor.as:0]
```

`byteArray` is correct, I wrote him to the file in the disc and he worked in the Flash Player well. I read a lot of about sandbox, `allowLoadBytesCodeExecution`, external SWF files in AIR but I can't to solve this problem!

How to load swf file from byteArray?

Answer (score 2):

I may be a bit late but I stumbled accross this while searching for my own problem. Try replacing your constructor call with this instead.

```
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
```